# Divide specific values in a column by 1000

Tags: r, divide

I need to divide certain values in a column by `1000` but do not know how to go about it

I attempted to use this function initially:

```
test <- Updins(weight,)

test$weight <- as.numeric(test$weight) / 1000

head(test)
```

with `Updins` being the dataframe and `weight` the column just to see if it would at least divide the entire column by `1000` but no such luck. It did not recognise 'test' as a variable.

Can anyone provide any guidance? I'm very new to R :)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Do you need `Updins$weight <- Updins$weight/1000` ?

Answer (score 0):

If 'Updins is the dataset object name, we can select the columns with `[` and not with `(` as `(` is used for function invoke

```
test <- Updins['weight']
test$weight <- as.numeric(test$weight) / 1000
```

Comment: the first line ran fine but the second line came up with this error: 'NAs introduced by coercion'

Comment: @belrey it is not an error., but a warning If you have non-numeric values in the column, it is converted to NA i.e. `as.numeric(1, 2, 'a')` results in 'a' getting converted to NA

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fake data set to divide all rows by 1000. I also included a for-loop as one potential way to only do this for certain rows. Since you didn't specify how you were doing that, I just did it for any rows that had a value greater than 1,005, and I did a second version for only dividing by 1,000 if the ID was an odd number. If you have NAs this you may need an addition if statement to deal with them. I will provide an example for that in the third/last for-loop example.

```
ID<-1:10
grams<-1000:1009

df<-data.frame(ID,grams)

df$kg<-as.numeric(df$grams)/1000
df[,"kg"]<-as.numeric(df[,"grams"])/1000 #will do the same thing as the line above

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df[i,"grams"]>1005){df[i,"kg3"]<-as.numeric(df[i,"grams"])/1000}
}#if the weight is greater than 1,005 grams.

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df[i,"ID"] %in% seq(1,101, by = 2)){df[i,"kg4"]<-as.numeric(df[i,"grams"])/1000}
}#if the id is an odd number



df[3,"grams"]<-NA#add an NA to the weight data to test the next loop
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(is.na(df[i,"grams"]) & (df[i,"ID"] %in% seq(1,101, by = 2))){df[i,"kg4"]<-NA}
           else if(df[i,"ID"] %in% seq(1,101, by = 2)){df[i,"kg4"]<-as.numeric(df[i,"grams"])/1000}
}#Same as above, but works with NAs
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard without data to work with or expected output, but here's a skeleton that you could probably use:

```
library(dplyr) #The package you'll need, for the pipes (%>% -- passes objects from one line to the next)
test <- Updins %>% #Using the dataset Updins
   mutate(weight = ifelse(as.numeric(weight) > 199, #CHANGING weight variable. #Where weight > 50...
                          as.character(as.numeric(weight)/1000), #... divide a numeric version of the weight variable by 1000, but keep as a character... 
                          weight) #OTHERWISE, keep the weight variable as is
head(test)
```

I kept the new value as a character, because it seems that your `weight` variable is a character variable based on some of the warnings ('`NAs introduced by coercion`') that you're getting.

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you! Although now I'm receiving an error saying 'Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "list" '.                               
I altered the code a bit to display ' library(dplyr::select()) #The package you'll need, for the pipes (%>% -- passes objects from one line to the next)
test <- Updins %>% #Using the dataset Updins
  mutate(weight = ifelse(as.numeric(weight) > 199, #CHANGING weight variable. #Where weight > 50...
                         as.character(as.numeric(weight)/1000), weight)) '

Comment: Remove the '::select()' from the library argument. What you wrote says "from the package dplyr, use the function select" which isn't what you want. You want to load the ENTIRE dplyr package and all of its functions/prerequisites. You might need to run install.packages("dplyr") first.

Comment: Also hard to say why you're getting that error without data. Can you provide some fake data to work with?