# In R: conditionally dividing numeric values by 1000

Tags: r

I have found similar code but not ones that identify a condition that the code should only apply to numeric observations, and am therefore asking this question.
This is the link I found most similar: [Divide specific values in a column by 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64288035/divide-specific-values-in-a-column-by-1000)

I would like to divide all numeric observations (of a dataset) with amount_code == 1 by 1,000,000 (1 million), and all numeric observations (of a dataset) with amount_code == 2 by 1,000 (1 thousand).
I tried the code below, but to bo honest I am probably way off in being right (I am very new to this):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, amount_code == 1, ./1000000)
```

This is what I have (but in reality way more numeric variables):

```
amount_code     value    
      1        123456
      1        234567
      2        123456
      2        234567
```

This is what I would want:

```
amount_code    value    
      1       0.123456
      1       0.234567
      2       123.456
      2       234.567
```

Any help is super appreciated! thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `case_when` to specify multiple conditions.  The `mutate_if` can be replaced with `across/where` (as it is deprecated)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
   mutate(across(c(where(is.numeric), - amount_code),
   ~ case_when(amount_code == 1~ ./ 1000000, 
       amount_code == 2 ~ ./1000)))
```

-output

```
df1
#  amount_code      value
#1           1   0.123456
#2           1   0.234567
#3           2 123.456000
#4           2 234.567000
```

NOTE: the `across` is used assuming there are multiple columns to be divided

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(amount_code = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), value = c(123456L, 
234567L, 123456L, 234567L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: it seems to do the opposite for me. when I apply the code, the character and integer variables are divided by 1000 or 1000000 rather than the numeric variables. Instead the numeric variables end up with NA values. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @coding_sailor I updated the code.  May be you were using the old code.  I used a condition within `where`, which i changed.  Can you try again

Comment: perfect, thank you!! I must have just missed your edit :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `case_when` since there is only one value column.

```
df <- tribble(
~amount_code,     ~value ,   
1, 123456, 
1, 234567, 
2, 123456, 
2, 234567)

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when(amount_code==1 ~ value/1000000,
                           amount_code==2 ~ value/1000))

# Output:
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  amount_code   value
        <dbl>   <dbl>
1           1   0.123
2           1   0.235
3           2 123.   
4           2 235.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
df <- tibble(amount_code=c(1,1,2,2), 
     value  =c(123456,234567,123456,234567))

  df  %>% 
     mutate(value2= case_when(
       amount_code == 1 ~ value/1000000,
       T ~ value/1000
     ))
```